# Valdiar que exista almenos uno de los dos apellidos Laravel validate rule

Tags: laravel, input, validate

Esto es simple, tengo un formulario con dos inputs

Apellido_Paterno y Apellido_Materno.

La idea es poder validar esto con Laravel, que al momento de enviar mis datos deba existir uno de ellos dos o los dos a la vez. Pero no pueden venir los dos vacios....

```
  public function register(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'apellido_paterno' => 'required',
            'apellido_materno' => 'required',

        ]);
    }
```

No se si esto es posible con una regla de validacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias utilizar la regla `required_without` para chequear que al menos uno de los dos haya sido enviado.
Algo asi:

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'apellido_paterno' => 'required_without:apellido_materno',
  'apellido_materno' => 'required_without:apellido_paterno',
]);
```

Aqui esta la documentacion (en ingles) sobre las reglas: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-without)

Answer (score 0):

si,se puede
crea una request

php artisan make:request nombreRequest
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).